# Getting a property from a mocked model's relationship (Laravel, PHPUnit)

Tags: php, laravel, orm, phpunit, laravel-8

In the code I have this:

```
if (!$check = $this->getCheck()) {
    return false;
}

if (!$user = $check->user) {
    return false;
}


$user->verification->some_id;
```

Method `getCheck` is in a trait which is used by a service, which I am mocking by binding it in the test

```
$app->bind(Service::class, function () {
    return $this->mock(Service::class, function(MockInterface $mock) {
        $mock->makePartial();

        $check = app(Check::class);

        $expect = $mock->shouldReceive('getCheck');

        $expect->andReturn($check);
    }
});
```

I want to mock `getCheck` so that it returns a `check` model with a `user` model which has a `verification` model which has the property `some_id`

I read about using with(), but just can't seem to get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Laravel` you should not mock Models, there is weird side effects with it. You can without a problem use models without saving them to the database, which i assume is the best approach for you.

```
$check = new Check();
$check->user = new User();

$expect->andReturn($check);
```

If the models are needed for database connections, you need to have a local test database either `Sqlite` or a proper `SQL` server. Using factories to create the test data you need.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I ended up doing. Seemed like a pretty simple solution after all that I had tried, but it does what I need.

Comment: Yes, in general mocking Models is never the approach to take. And i have now in my lifetime written a unit test or two :)